# Mongodb "admin" with unlimited access running into authentication errors?

Tags: mongodb

```
> use admin;
switched to db admin

> db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})
{
    "authInfo" : {
        "authenticatedUsers" : [
            {
                "user" : "admin",
                "db" : "admin"
            }
        ],
        "authenticatedUserRoles" : [
            {
                "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "role" : "clusterAdmin",
                "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            }
        ]
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.grantRolesToUser("admin", [{role: "readWrite", db: "mydatabase"}])
2019-11-02T21:53:23.576+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: not authorized on admin to execute command { grantRolesToUser: "admin", roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "mydatabase" } ], writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 600000.0 }, lsid: { id: UUID("7f945e1d-4165-4f23-9e83-d209e81d5417") }, $db: "admin" } :
```

Here is the summary for my issue

1. I created an admin user with almost unlimited access
2. I authenticated with this admin user and tried to grant a role
3. I get unauthenticated error???

Running mongodb 4.2 on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grant roles, you need the [grantRole action permission](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/index.html#required-access). This action is available in the [userAdmin built-in role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/index.html#userAdmin).

Your `admin` user currently only has `readWriteAnyDatabase`, `clusterAdmin`, and `dbAdminAnyDatabase` roles. You need to add `userAdmin` to that list to allow it to grant additional roles to another user.